# How to get input from tkinter Entry widget on second window while the first window continues to run

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, input, widget, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *

def first():
    root1 = Tk()

    Button(root1, text = 'get Second', command= second).pack()

    root1.mainloop()


def second():
    root2 = Tk()

    user_input = StringVar()

    Entry(root2, text  = user_input).pack()

    Button(root2, text = 'submit', command  = lambda : print(user_input.get(), '\t printed')).pack()

    root2.mainloop()

first()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a few basic mistakes in here -

1. You if want to use a second window, it should be Toplevel not root Tk window. There should be only one root window in the program. This should act as parent to all the windows.
2. Its a good practice in most of the cases to define the widgets like Button, Entry separately and then pack() them.
3. Entry should have 'textvariable' not 'text'

Following is the updated code which may help you -

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def first():

    button = Button(root, text = 'get Second', command= second)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

def second():
    window2 = Toplevel(root)

    user_input = StringVar()

    entry = Entry(window2, textvariable=user_input)
    entry.pack()

    button = Button(window2, text = 'submit', command  = lambda: print(user_input.get()))
    button.pack()

first()
```